# cURL -d switch: How to use it in a guzzle request

Tags: php, curl

I'm learning to use an API. They provide an example of the following authentication code:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "   {\"Username\": \"the_username\",
    \"Password\": \"the_password\"}
   " "https://someurl.someapi.com:443/api/Login/Authenticate"
```

However I need to reproduce this with a Guzzle request. Here is what I've been trying

```
   $headers = [
      "Content-Type" =>  "application/json",
      "Accept" => 'application/json -d " {\"Username\": \"the_username\", \"Password\": \"the_password\" }" ',
   ];

//    $headers = [
//       "Content-Type" =>  "application/json"
//    ];

   
   $extra_data = ["proxy"    => $proxy,
                  "headers"  => $headers ];
     
   // Defining the Guzzle Client to communicate with Legacy.com 
   $client = new Client([
       // Base URI is used with relative requests
       'base_uri' => 'https://someurl.someapi.com:443/api/Login/Authenticate',
       // You can set any number of default request options.
       'timeout'  => 10.0,
   ]);
   
   try {
      $response = $client->request('POST', '', $extra_data);
   }
```

However no matter what I try (this was the latest of my failed attempts), I can't get anything other than a code 400 error.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured how to do this:

This code worked!

```
   $str = json_decode('{ "Username": "' . $username . '", "Password": "' . $password  . '"}',true);
   
   var_dump($str);
   
   if ($str == NULL) return;
   
   $url_authenticate = "Login/Authenticate";
   $extra_data = ["proxy"    => $proxy,
                  "json"     => $str ];
   
   // Defining the Guzzle Client to communicate with Legacy.com 
   $client = new Client([
       // Base URI is used with relative requests
       'base_uri' => 'https://someurl.someapi.com:443/api/',
       // You can set any number of default request options.
       'timeout'  => 10.0,
   ]);
   
   try {
      $response = $client->request('POST', $url_authenticate, $extra_data);
   }   
   catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() .  "\n";
      exit;
   }      
   
   $body = $response->getBody();

   echo $body;
```

The key was use the json field int the extra data and transform the json to php array using json_decode. I hope this helps someone else